# Python: How to find indices of elements that satisfy conditions in each row, and transformed them to a dict?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

An example:

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(20211021)
myarray = np.random.randint(0, 5, size=(5, 4))

>>> myarray
array([[2, 3, 0, 1],
       [3, 3, 3, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 2, 4, 0],
       [4, 1, 4, 0]])
```

Here I use `argwhere` in `numpy` to find indices of elements that greater than 0 in each row.

```py
g0 = np.argwhere(myarray > 0)
>>> g0
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 3],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [2, 0],
       [3, 0],
       [3, 1],
       [3, 2],
       [4, 0],
       [4, 1],
       [4, 2]], dtype=int64)
```

The dices `g0` is a two-dimension array. The form of indices that I intend to create is like below:

```py
{
    0: [0, 1, 3],
    1: [0, 1, 2, 3],
    2: [0],
    3: [0, 1, 2],
    4: [0, 1, 2]
}
```

Is there any way in which `g0` can be transformed to a dict?
(Other than applying function to each row of `myarray` I hasn't find an efficient method)

Comment: building a dictionary with a `for` loop is not that bad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) can be used with indexes to get both the dictionary keys and locations, then use [`np.split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) to divide the array, then [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) together the keys and the arrays to build the dictionary from the tuples:

```
g0 = np.argwhere(myarray > 0)
keys, locs = np.unique(g0[:, 0], return_index=True)
d = dict(zip(keys, np.split(g0[:, 1], locs[1:])))
```

[`np.nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) may be faster than [`np.argwhere`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) in this case:

```
i, v = np.nonzero(myarray > 0)
keys, locs = np.unique(i, return_index=True)
d = dict(zip(keys, np.split(v, locs[1:])))
```

However, a simple dictionary comprehension is likely the fastest option on smaller arrays:

```
d = {i: np.nonzero(r > 0)[0] for i, r in enumerate(myarray)}
```

All options produce `d`:

```
{0: array([0, 1, 3]),
 1: array([0, 1, 2, 3]),
 2: array([0]),
 3: array([0, 1, 2]),
 4: array([0, 1, 2])}
```

---

Setup and imports:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(20211021)
myarray = np.random.randint(0, 5, size=(5, 4))
```